# How can i find link between two dataframes and sort them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a Dataframe like:

| SW Source | SW Version | Country | Verification Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a567dfga | b869df0a | China | XYZ-1010 |
| b869df0a | j678900a | Brazil | XYZ-1011 |
| j678900a | yur686fh | Portugal | XYZ-1012 |

How can i track the sw launch Order without deploy dates respecting the respective release country?

Some facts About:

- The first Version dont have a target version pointing to it
- the last version don't have a sw with his source build(since it inst released)
- We cant discard countrys

Somehow i need to put in order like this:

| SW Source | SW Version | Country | Verification Code | Order Nr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a567dfga | b869df0a | China | XYZ-1010 | 1 |
| a567dfga | b869df0a | Brazil | XYZ-1011 | 1 |
| a567dfga | b869df0a | Portugal | XYZ-1012 | 1 |
| b869df0a | j678900a | China | XYZ-1010 | 2 |
| b869df0a | j678900a | Brazil | XYZ-1011 | 2 |
| b869df0a | j678900a | Portugal | XYZ-1012 | 2 |
| j678900a | yur686fh | China | XYZ-1010 | 3 |
| j678900a | yur686fh | Brazil | XYZ-1011 | 3 |
| j678900a | yur686fh | Portugal | XYZ-1012 | 3 |

Comment: Your question is really unclear right now. Your title mentions two dataframes. What are they? Various terms you use in the question all need to be explained ("launch order", "deploy dates", "first version", "last version", "target version", "source build"). Please refer to [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
df
###
  SW Source SW Version   Country Verification Code
0  a567dfga   b869df0a  Portugal          XYZ-1012
1  b869df0a   j678900a  Portugal          XYZ-1012
2  a567dfga   b869df0a     China          XYZ-1010
3  a567dfga   b869df0a    Brazil          XYZ-1011
4  b869df0a   j678900a     China          XYZ-1010
5  j678900a   yur686fh     China          XYZ-1010
6  b869df0a   j678900a    Brazil          XYZ-1011
7  j678900a   yur686fh  Portugal          XYZ-1012
8  j678900a   yur686fh    Brazil          XYZ-1011
```

Sort & Cluster

```
df.sort_values(['SW Source', 'SW Version','Verification Code'], inplace=True)
df['cluster'] = df.groupby(['SW Source','SW Version']).grouper.group_info[0]+1
df
###
  SW Source SW Version   Country Verification Code  cluster
0  a567dfga   b869df0a     China          XYZ-1010        1
1  a567dfga   b869df0a    Brazil          XYZ-1011        1
2  a567dfga   b869df0a  Portugal          XYZ-1012        1
3  b869df0a   j678900a     China          XYZ-1010        2
4  b869df0a   j678900a    Brazil          XYZ-1011        2
5  b869df0a   j678900a  Portugal          XYZ-1012        2
6  j678900a   yur686fh     China          XYZ-1010        3
7  j678900a   yur686fh    Brazil          XYZ-1011        3
8  j678900a   yur686fh  Portugal          XYZ-1012        3
```